# Why is the horse so valuable in Blade Runner 2049?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

Dr Badger thinks that K's little wooden horse is extremely valuable, and yet outside Sapper Morton's house there is an entire tree, which no one remarks on.

Answer (score 11):

## It's *real* wood, so it's rare

In the *Blade Runner* universe, much of the 'natural' things of the world have been diminished or destroyed, to due various unexplained reasons - including wars, floods and pollution. As such, *real* things in the world - unreplicated objects - are actually seen to be quite valuable, given their rarity.

We are to assume that the wood used to carve K's horse is in fact *real* wood. There is no indication that Sapper's tree (get it?) is real so it would become worthless. Besides, even if it was real, the only person who knows about it is Sapper himself and now K.

To add to all of that, remember when Mariette meets K in the market, and she remarks toward the picture of Sapper's tree that she's never seen one? This tells us that in truth - at least in the Megalopolis' - people may not have seen *real* wood.

When Dr. Badger tells K that he's willing to manufacture a living horse (Replicant version) and trade it for the piece of wood that K has, it tells us that those items are in fact rare, and therefore valuable.

Now juxtapose that with Niander Wallace's living quarters, which is decadently furnished almost entirely with wood. This shows his power and status.

Comment: It's also possible that Sapper's tree could be rotten through, so the wood wouldn't be workable any more. The thing looks dead,  desiccated even, it's white, has no leaves and is possibly only standing thanks to a bunch of tethers. We don't know what happened to the trees, but if it was something along these lines, it would make items of worked wood increasingly rare/valuable.

Comment: Wouldn't the dirty area Deckard is living in presumably have a lot of real wood? It looks relatively untouched and apparently of no threat to replicants. You'd think they would pillage the area for all furniture, building moldings, etc.

Comment: @KaiQing If you want that question answered, you can always ask about it on this site.

Comment: @KaiQing `You'd think they would pillage the area` or leave it the hell alone because it's contaminatedAF!

Comment: @Möoz - maybe the surface is but there's still a lot that may not have been saturated. I'm just saying they make a big deal out of a little wooden horse. If that shred of wood is worth so much or is so impressive, what's stopping replicants from entering an area they aren't affected by and digging deep down where the presumably less irradiated resources are? I assume they haven't because everything appeared to be in decent shape for a post apocalyptic setting